# Binding.scala FXML: How to populate an ObservableList property

Tags: scala, javafx, binding.scala

I have code like this:

```
val state = Var(initialState)

// ...
type SavedSearchCmb = ComboBox[SavedSearch]
val savedSearchesCmb: Binding[SavedSearchCmb] =
  <SavedSearchCmb>
    <items>
      {state.bind.savedSearches}
    </items>
  </SavedSearchCmb>
```

The compiler complains,

> ```
> [error]  found   : Seq[com.dev1on1.timer.YouTrackAPI.SavedSearch]
> [error]  required: javafx.collections.ObservableList[com.dev1on1.timer.YouTrackAPI.SavedSearch]
> [error]         <items>
> ```

What's the right way to generate the items?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the specification of FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements):

> A read-only list property is a Bean property whose getter returns an instance of `java.util.List` and has no corresponding setter method. The contents of a read-only list element are automatically added to the list as they are processed.

`items` is a list property of `SavedSearchCmb`, however, it is not **read-only** as there is a setter [setItems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#setItems-javafx.collections.ObservableList-). As a result, the previous version of Binding.scala does append content of the `savedSearches` to the `items` property, instead, it tries to assign the `Constants` to `items` via `setItems`.

That is to say, the previous behavior of Binding.scala is extractly correct according to the specification.

---

The FXML behavior is very inconvenient.

Fortunately, Binding.scala does not have to support the extractly same syntax of Oracle's `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader`.

I decide to break the specification, allowing appending content of the data-binding expressions to any list properties, no matter it is read-only or not.

The change has been include in [Binding.scala 11.0.1](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/releases/tag/v11.0.1). Your code should compile if you upgrade to Binding.scala 11.0.1.

We can do better than the original FXML specification. That's why you choose Binding.scala over `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader`.

Comment: Thanks. What if instead of a Seq I have a `BindingSeq`?

Comment: I guess I can do `.all.bind` and then wrap?

Comment: `.all.bind` compiles but loses the ability of partial update

Comment: Right, so ideally there would be something to convert a BindingSeq to an ObservableList preserving the partial update behavior

Comment: IIRC, there are auto-conversions from `Seq` and `BindingSeq` to `ObservableList`. 

If it does not work, could you minimize your example and report it on Binding.scala's issue tracker?